# errors in DrawerLayout and appindex google play API

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I got some errors in DrawerLayout and Google appindex API!!
I'm going to crazy with this IntelliJ Android Studio :(

here is DrawerLayout :

[DL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh8aW.jpg)

here is error messages :
[EM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRE4d.jpg)

and here is my HomaActivity (MainActivity) code:

```
    package ir.homa;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.HashMap;
import ir.homa.SQLiteHandler;
import ir.homa.SessionManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;


public class HomaActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private TextView txtName;
    private TextView txtEmail;
    private Button btnLogout;

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homa);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);


        // SqLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            logoutUser();
        }

        // Fetching user details from sqlite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        String name = user.get("name");
        String email = user.get("email");

        // Displaying the user details on the screen
        txtName.setText(name);
        txtEmail.setText(email);

        // Logout button click event
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logoutUser();
            }
        });
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
     * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
     */
    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);

        db.deleteUsers();

        // Launching the login activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomaActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.homa, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Homa Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://ir.homa/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Homa Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://ir.homa/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I have some errors about Google Play AppIndex in middle of those errors!
help..!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homa);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);


    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }

    // Fetching user details from sqlite
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

    String name = user.get("name");
    String email = user.get("email");

    // Displaying the user details on the screen
    txtName.setText(name);
    txtEmail.setText(email);

    // Logout button click event
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            logoutUser();
        }
    });
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}






/**
 * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
 * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
 */
private void logoutUser() {
    session.setLogin(false);

    db.deleteUsers();

    // Launching the login activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(HomaActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: I put it under onCreate bruckets

Comment: put the code related to drawerlayout and navigationview inside onCreate curly braces